# Use ajax not working in views block displayed programmatically

Tags: 7, views

I have a view with a block display. In the "OTHER" area of the view settings, I checked "Use Ajax".

I display this block programmatically inside a node in this way

```
print $view->render('block_1');
```

The block is displayed, but when I use the pager to go to the next page of the results, ajax is not used and the page is reloaded with "page=1" added to the url.

any idea?
thank you

**I found the solution**

To have the "use ajax" working, you have to render the view using:

```
$view->set_display('block_1');
print $view->preview('block_1');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

To have the "use ajax" working, you have to render the view using:

```
$view->set_display('block_1');
print $view->preview('block_1');
```