# Use AJAX not working when view is rendered programmatically

Tags: 8, views

I have a view that is being rendered like this

```
$view = Views::getView('view_id');
$view->setDisplay('block_1');
$view->execute();
$render = $view->render(); 
$html = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($render);
```

The $html variable is being returned in the build method of a Block

```
public function build() {
    return array(
      '#theme' => 'theme_template',
      '#view' => $html,
    );
  }
```

Then being outputted in the twig file `{{ view }}`

The view is being rendered but the pagination does not use ajax instead it reloads the page with the query string ?page=1

I have found a similar question but this is for drupal 7:
[Use ajax not working in views block displayed programmatically](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/134316/use-ajax-not-working-in-views-block-displayed-programmatically)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't render too early and you don't need to, templates can print render arrays. Also Views provides already a block plugin: /core/modules/views/src/Plugin/Block/ViewsBlock.php.

Comment: Hi @4k4, thanks for replying! I have tried to use the $render variable instead but still the ajax is not being used. Im going to look into ViewsBlock but do you have any links on how to use it?

Comment: `do you have any links on how to use it?` @StephanSutter you just go to `/admin/structure/block` and place it like any other block. You can give it visibility restriction so it only appears on certain page(s).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
public function build() {
    $view = Views::getView('view_name');
    $view->setDisplay('block_1');
    $view->execute();
    return [
        '#type' => 'view',
        '#name' => 'view_name',
        '#view' => $view,
        '#display_id' => 'block_1',
        '#embed' => TRUE,
        '#cache' => $view->getCacheTags(),
    ];
}
```

If not use [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) and on the block's or page's template file do

```
{{ drupal_view('view_name', 'block_1') }}
```

> Twig Tweak module provides a Twig extension with some useful functions
> and filters that can improve developer experience.